# How do you push a value to a jQuery data() object from an element?

Tags: jquery

Suppose you have this:

```
<a href="#" data-mydata="{'key':[value1, value2, value3]}">LINK</a>
```

And somewhere in your javascript when you are reading/checking that data you want to push more values to 'key.'

This obviously does not work:

```
var mykey = $('a').data('mydata').key;
$('a').data('mydata', mykey.push('value4'));
```

This doesn't work either:

```
var mykey = $('a').data('mydata').key;
$('a').data('mydata.key', mykey.push('value4'));
```

I haven't found this to work either:

```
var mykey = $('a').data('mydata').key;
$('a').data('mydata', '{"key":'+mykey.push('value4')+'}');
```

I must be missing something here.

Comment: `mykey.push('value4')` return numbers of array items, not a value or values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update `mykey` directly:

```
var mykey = $('a').data('mydata').key;
mykey.push('value4');
console.log(mykey); //                   ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
console.log($('a').data('mydata').key)// ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ewDaB/

***Note: I fixed your data attribute to have valid json so that jQuery can parse it as an object properly. Also wrapped values in quotes.***

Comment: I have no idea why I couldn't get this to work before. I tried this as well, and I just forgot the quotes around the [] here, had them in my code. Also, you don't have to have the values wrapped in quotes if the values are numeric, the example code was not clear with that I guess.

Comment: Correct, as long as it's valid json it's good, i assumed you had valid json, that's why i mentioned it as a note and not actually part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eval works but considered dangerous as gdoron mentioned. The way to set objects in jQuery data is by just setting them without serializing them yourself. So best way is to do this:

```
values = $('a').data('mydata').key;
values.push('value4')
$('a').data('mydata', {'key': values});
```

But this means you shouldn't set the data-mydata attribute on the html element that way, instead you should set it dynamically with jQuery:

```
$('a').data('mydata', {'key': [value1, value2, value3] });
```

You can call this on page load to init the data on an element. jQuery will take care of serializing the data and saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be work:

```
var mykey = $('a').data('mydata').key;
mykey.push('value4');
$('a').data('mydata', mykey);
```

I'm not sure about last line, but you can try here with you three examples. But use array not arra.push as a value.